# Why is Eclipse Juno on my Lenovo W530 with 12.04 so slow?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, eclipse, lenovo

I got a new **Lenovo W530** with 16 GB of RAM and 280 GB SSD with NVIDIA Quadro K2000M Graphics with 2GB DDR3 Memory.

After trying to make 12.10 to work with dual external monitor and failed, I moved to 12.04.

My problem is with compiz and Eclipse:
First, Eclipse is very slow - the search screen can take 30 seconds to load (the display becomes grey and after 30-60 seconds it is live again). 
Actually I can't work with Eclipse because of this problem.

I removed all the plugins and marked the other to not load at start up.
I changed in my `eclipse.ini` to `-Xms512m -Xmx1024m` and then to `-Xmx4096m`.

In addition to this problem - generally it seems like compiz is killing my coputer - it consumes up to 10 GB of RAM.

I tried to log-in with Ubuntu 2D - and the Eclipse problem is still there.

I tried using gnome-classic but:
a. It has problems of its own (alt-shift not working, etc.)
b. I don't want to give up on Unity - I really like it.

I'm not sure if the problems are related.
Please remember that I'm new in the Linux world.

--**Update**

I've got back to Indigo and everything is working great. still, Juno has some great features...

Comment: Please ask only one question per post, you can move the second question to a new post.

Comment: not sure what you mean. it seems like the problems are related.

Comment: Sir, I am experiencing the same problem as you have with Rational Software Architect which is Eclipse based. I wonder if you can update your post if the update of nvidia driver did resolve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

This is is the progress I have made on this problem.  I don't agree that my original post was deleted because I was providing content in the spirit of this forum: "Help us find a solution by researching the problem, then contribute the results of your research and anything additional you’ve tried as a partial answer"

As in my deleted post, I put more details of the problem in order for the original poster to compare the behavior and decide whether the problem I am addressing is the same as his.  Frequently, eclipse juno on ubuntu 12.10 is unresponsive (its window turns grey), and cpu utilization of both compiz and xorg shoot way up to 60-75% each (measured with top). It could be related to eclipse's search dialog, but might be related to any of its dialogs; I have not noticed.

The solutions I attempted which had limited effect:

1) disabling compiz effects: (reputation not good enough to post the link).  Drops compiz cpu utlization to acceptable level, but xorg's cup utlization is still much to high: 70-80%.

2) disabling scroll bar overlay.  (reputation not good enough to post the link).  The problem still occurs after this but is significantly shortened, from 30 seconds to about 3 seconds.

Currently I am testing this solution which seems to have positive result after a few hours:

1) upgrading nvidia driver: http://www.noobslab.com/2011/09/nvidia-drivers-for-ubuntu-1110-oneiric.html.

If eclipse response is still poor, I will continue to research and post findings here, unless this answer is deleted.

Comment: juno sr2 was released today.  It has performance improvements.